# Why isn't my dropdown input arrow showing?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a very basic form using Bootstrap 4, and my dropdown field isn't showing the default "arrow down" icon it should show. Also, my form has a checkbox, and the checkbox itself isn't showing either.  I can't figure out why this is happening, since in the [Bootstrap's example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) it does show.

You can see my [codepen here](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/dyXgmZx?editors=1100).

```css
/* General Styles */

* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
}

.input-normal,
.input-dropdown {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #495057;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="publicationServiceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="publicationServiceModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <img src="images/logo-header.svg" alt="Logo Reebit" class="col-lg-4">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Form -->
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select required class="form-control input-dropdown" id="serviceCategorySelection">
              <option>¿Qué servicio ofreces?</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input required type="text" class="form-control input-normal" id="serviceName" aria-describedby="serviceName" placeholder="Nombre del servicio">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control input-normal" id="serviceDescription" rows="3" placeholder="Escribe información relevante sobre tu servicio"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select required class="form-control input-dropdown" id="serviceRegion">
              <option>Región</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select required class="form-control input-dropdown" id="serviceComuna">
              <option>Comuna</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="whatsappCheck">

          </div>


        </form>
        <!-- /Form -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Modal -->
```

Comment: You don't appear to have included any CSS (even the bootstrap) in your example, so at the moment all we are seeing is the browser default.

Comment: `I haven't applied any CSS yet` This is why.

Comment: I added the Bootstrap CSS to the example, and it shows the "arrow down"... Even without any CSS, it shows the arrow down.

Comment: Even *with* the Bootstrap CDN, we can still see the down arrow.

Comment: There's a difference between the user not having added their own CSS, and the user not having included the bootstrap file, which is what I was pointing out.

Comment: @HereticMonkey You should put the CSS into your own answer, rather than editing the question itself to correct what you think the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: You must at least include the bootstrap CSS. By including it I can see the arrow.

Comment: @Martin the OP says, "I'm creating a very basic form using Bootstrap 4" I think it is safe to say that they are using Bootstrap 4. I was not attempting to answer the question. Thanks.

Comment: After your latest edit, the question makes more sense. Please check my edited answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### After OP Edit:

The icon's showing on the [Bootstap example page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) are part of the [custom forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-forms).

You'll need the `custom-select` class to enable those;

```
<select required class="custom-select form-control input-dropdown" id="serviceCategorySelection">
```

[Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/0stone0/pen/vYKVRbG?editors=1100)

---

#### Before OP Edit:

You'll need to load Bootstrap's [`css` file](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/).

---

The easiest way is to use a [CDN link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/);

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

---

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group">
  <select required class="form-control input-dropdown" id="serviceRegion">
    <option>Región</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using the CDN.  The weird thing is that when I add a `border: 1px solid red` un my CSS; the arrow icon dissapears.

Comment: You should include that in your question. It sound like you have a whole different question...

Comment: @Paula Please see [mcve]. Include the problem-causing CSS in the question itself. We need to be able to reproduce your issue to fix it.

Comment: Adding the `custom-select` class solved the dropdown icon issue.  However, the checkbox "box" is still not showing. Any thoughts on this?